# ¿Cómo convierto una cadena a booleano en C#?

Tags: c#, string, booleano

Esta pregunta es auto respondida, y la respuesta es una traducción de [mi respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49590775/9443618) a la misma en el sitio en inglés.

---

Tengo esta cadena:

```
string cadena = "True";
```

Y necesito que sea un booleano:

```
bool condicion = true;
```

Intenté convertirla, de esta forma:

```
bool condicion = (bool) cadena;
```

Pero obtengo el error `CS0029` que me indica que no puedo convertir implícitamente el tipo `string` a `bool`.

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# ofrece diversas opciones que permiten convertir un valor de cadena a su equivalente booleano.

Tenemos a [`bool.Parse(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.boolean.parse?view=net-7.0) y su equivalente [`System.Convert.ToBoolean(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.convert.toboolean?view=net-7.0).

Ambos son casi lo mismo, reciben como entrada una cadena, que debe ser una representación de cadena válida para un booleano y que además es insensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas. Es decir:

```
bool.Parse("True")  // Correcto, devuelve true
bool.Parse("true")  // Correcto, devuelve true
bool.Parse("TRUE")  // Correcto, devuelve true
bool.Parse("trUE")  // Correcto, devuelve true
bool.Parse("TRue")  // Correcto, devuelve true

bool.Parse("False") // Correcto, devuelve false
bool.Parse("false") // Correcto, devuelve false
bool.Parse("FALSE") // Correcto, devuelve false
bool.Parse("faLSE") // Correcto, devuelve false
bool.Parse("FAlse") // Correcto, devuelve false
```

<sup>`System.Convert.ToBoolean` internamente implementa `bool.Parse`, por lo que para este caso son lo mismo.</sup>

Si la cadena de entrada no representa un booleano válido, entonces ambos métodos lanzan una `System.FormatException`:

```
bool.Parse("Manolo")             // System.FormatException: La cadena de entrada no tiene un formato válido
bool.Parse("1281")               // System.FormatException: La cadena de entrada no tiene un formato válido
bool.Parse("06/10/11 15:24:16")  // System.FormatException: La cadena de entrada no tiene un formato válido
```

<sup>`System.Convert.ToBoolean` internamente implementa `bool.Parse`, por lo que para este caso son lo mismo.</sup>

Si la cadena de entrada es `null`, entonces `bool.Parse` lanza una `System.ArgumentNullException` mientras que `System.Convert.ToBoolean` simplemente devuelve `false`.

```
bool.Parse(null)               // System.ArgumentNullException: El valor no puede ser nulo
System.Convert.ToBoolean(null) // Devuelve false
```

<sup>Esta es la diferencia entre ambos, la forma en que manejan los valores de entrada `null`.</sup>

Sabiendo esto, sabemos además que:

```
bool condicion = bool.Parse("true")                 // condicion es true
bool condicion = System.Convert.ToBoolean("FALSE")  // condicion es false
bool condicion = bool.Parse("Sí")                   // Lanza una System.FormatException
bool condicion = System.Convert.ToBoolean("No")     // Lanza una System.FormatException
bool condicion = bool.Parse(null)                   // Lanza una System.ArgumentNullException
bool condicion = System.Convert.ToBoolean(null)     // condicion es false
```

---

Además, existe [`bool.TryParse(string, out bool)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.boolean.tryparse?view=net-7.0).

Equivale a `bool.Parse`, con la diferencia de que devuelve `true` si pudo convertir el valor y `false` en caso contrario. El booleano resultante de la conversión lo otorga como [argumento de salida](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) `out bool`.

Debido a esto, este método no lanza excepción alguna. En caso de una excepción simplemente devolverá `false`:

```
bool success = bool.TryParse("True",  out bool result)   // success es true, result es true
bool success = bool.TryParse("true",  out bool result)   // success es true, result es true
bool success = bool.TryParse("TRue",  out bool result)   // success es true, result es true
bool success = bool.TryParse("trUE",  out bool result)   // success es true, result es true

bool success = bool.TryParse("False", out bool result)   // success es true, result es false
bool success = bool.TryParse("false", out bool result)   // success es true, result es false
bool success = bool.TryParse("FAlse", out bool result)   // success es true, result es false
bool success = bool.TryParse("faLSE", out bool result)   // success es true, result es false

bool success = bool.TryParse("Sí",    out bool result)   // sucess es false, result es false
bool success = bool.TryParse("No",    out bool result)   // sucess es false, result es false
bool success = bool.TryParse("1285",  out bool result)   // sucess es false, result es false
bool success = bool.TryParse(null,    out bool result)   // sucess es false, result es false
```

<sup>Este no tiene un equivalente directo en `System.Convert`</sup>

---

Proponer [`string.Equals(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=net-7.0) parece una apuesta arriesgada, pero funciona para algunos casos.

Los anteriores funcionan bastante bien, pues es para lo que fueron diseñados. No obstante, siempre existen alternativas que pueden funcionar si se saben utilizar. Esto no quiere decir que sean un sustituto de las implementaciones ya diseñadas para la tarea.

```
bool result = cadena == "True"  // Funciona si cadena es una representación de cadena válida
bool result = cadena == "False" // Funciona si cadena es una representación de cadena válida
```

Esta opción es muy propensa a fallar, aunque esto se puede minimizar:

```
bool result = cadena.Equals("true",  System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
bool result = cadena.Equals("false", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
bool result = cadena.Equals("TRUE",  System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
bool result = cadena.Equals("FALSE", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

bool result = cadena.ToLower() == "true"
bool result = cadena.ToLower() == "false"
bool result = cadena.ToUpper() == "TRUE"
bool result = cadena.ToUpper() == "FALSE"
```

Esta opción es imprecisa, sensible a valores `null` y en cierto modo, más costosa que las anteriores (no aplica a todos los casos).

- **¿La recomiendo?** Si puedes usar los anteriores, no.
- **¿La puedes usar?** Que no la recomiende no significa que no funcione para casos específicos. Está ahí, optar por ella es tu decisión.

---

Me encantan los [`métodos de extensión`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) de C#.

Te permiten hacer cosas raras como esta:

```
bool result = "True" .ToBoolean()
bool result = "False".ToBoolean()
```

Donde el secreto se revela con esta forma:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool ToBoolean(this string value)
    {
        if (bool.TryParse(value, out bool result))
        {
            return result;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

O con esta:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool ToBoolean(this string value)
    {
        bool.TryParse(value, out bool result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Si casteas el string así como haces, la excepción que obtienes es porque el compilador no sabe cómo va a convertir ese valor.

Para eso existen las funciones de conversión como estas:

```
string texto = "false";
bool b1 = bool.Parse(texto);
bool b2 = bool.TryParse(texto, out bool b) && b;
bool b3 = Convert.ToBool(texto);
```

que le indican al IDE cómo va a convertir, y te dejan poner la cultura al convertir, para que la conversión sea la de tu PC o igual para todos:

```
string texto = "false";
bool b1 = bool.Parse(texto, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
bool b2 = bool.TryParse(texto, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out bool b) && b;
bool b3 = Convert.ToBool(texto);
```